# Converting boost::multiprecision real number to integral ones

Tags: c++, boost, g++, decimal, bigdecimal

I am trying to convert a `boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_x` to a `boost::multiprecision::uintx_t`. So basically a boost bigreal to a boost bigint, with regards to memory needed for this conversion not to be lossy.
Consider the following:

```
boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_100 myreal(100); /* bigreal */
boost::multiprecision::uint256_t myint; /* bigint */
```

### Designing memory allocation

I want to make a conversion from the first to the last. Consider that I kept in count the number of bits needed for this. Starting from a 256-bit integer I need a float able to store from 0 to 2^256-1. How many digits do I need for this? Exactly `256*log_10(2) ~= 77`. So a 100 digit float is more than enough. So if I keep my real number lower than 2^256, I can convert it to a 256-bit integer.

How can I make the conversion considering that `convert_to<>` can only be used with built in types and `static_cast<>` raise errors (which is expected considering that the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/conversions.html) does not mention such a context)? Thankyou

### Do not care about data-loss

I do not care about data loss. For my purpose I will store (in the bigreal variable) an integer number (no decimal part). So I am just ok!

Comment: "I am trying to convert a boost::multiprecision::uintx_t to a boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_x" - haven't you mixed these around?

Comment: I changed and swapped places....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is you are looking for, try...

```
cpp_dec_float_100 myreal(100);
cpp_dec_float_100 int_part = myreal.backend().extract_integer_part();
```

The type is still cpp_dec_float_100, but only contains the integer part. 
I hope this helps.